# moran.test in R

Tags: r, correlation, spatial

I made moran test in R with alternative= "greater". There are the results:

```
Moran I statistic standard deviate = 4.8104, p-value = 7.532e-07
alternative hypothesis: greater
sample estimates:
Moran I statistic       Expectation          Variance 
      0.259352270      -0.005988024       0.003042599
```

Does it mean that there is positive autocorrelation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data does spatially cluster. We can also consider the p-value as a measure of the statistical significance of the model and the Moran I statistic is `0.26`, we can, therefore, determine that there our qualification variable is positively autocorrelated your map.